# Output strings to specific rows in excel with python

Tags: python

I have a list *MyList[]* of integers which I convert to binary strings and output to an excel table.

The code looks like:

```
        r = 2
        for x in MyList:
            binary_out = bin(x)[2:].zfill(9)  
            for ind, val in enumerate(str(binary_out)) :
                worksheet.write(r,ind+2,val)
            r+=1
```

and the output of binary string looks like:

[image]

*(Note:This is the binary output of the code above. The other data are generated in an earlier phase)*

This is so far OK.

I would like to get the output only on specific rows, not to all. 
The information on which rows they have to be output I have only in form of indices which I have earlier collect into a list:

```
indices = [2,4,6,7]
```

As you can see above, the output in excel starts from row 2. 
So the row 2 shall now mean the number with the first index of *indices*.
So the output shall looks like:

[image]

How to modify the code to get the output on the wanted rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use nested for:

```
for x in MyList:
    binary_out = bin(x)[2:].zfill(9)  
    for row_idx in indices:
        for ind, val in enumerate(str(binary_out)):
            worksheet.write(row_idx,ind+2,val)
```

I do not know exactly what library you are using so I don't know what `ind` and `val` are.

Comment: Thanks! This worked. I just needed to increment all numbers in indices with 2, because I start from r = 2.

Comment: You are welcome, glad it helped!!Please upvote if it was useful!

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically create list with that `indices` using list comprehansion:

```
# for x in MyList:
for x in (MyList[idx] for idx in indices):
```

Comment: Have tried it already but it outputs me the strings in 4 consecutive rows, not in the wanted rows

Comment: @JohnDoe maybe your indices list not contains what you want, try this: `for x in (MyList[idx] for idx in [2, 4, 6, 7]):`

Comment: Yes the indices are already there, have checked this with print(indices). Have tried also to hardcode them, so I still get the output in the first 4 rows

Comment: @JohnDoe either indexes or a list itself contains not that you expect, check list if indexes are ok

Comment: They have everything. The answer marked as solution below works. But thanks also for you support!